# How to obtain a tumblr post ID after creating it with Tumblr PHP API?

Tags: php, api, tumblr

If I have setup a script to post a blog post to Tumblr using their API.

```
$client->createPost($blog->name, array(
                        'type' => 'link',
                        'tags' => '',
                        'title' => $post->title,
                        'description' => $body[0],
                        'url' => site_url($post->blog_slug),
                        'thumbnail' => base_url() . $post->preview_image
                    )
                );
```

Does anyone know how I can obtain the ID of this post that has been newly created? AFAIK the documentation doesn't say anything about obtaining the ID of the post after creating it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure—like you say, the documentation's not too clear—but I think [this section applies to all responses](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#common-fields). What do you see if you `var_dump` what you get back from the `createPost` call? Because I'm thinking there'll be a `posts` field with an `id` in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the id attribute of response returned by createPost method.

```
$response = $client->createPost($blog->name, array(
                    'type' => 'link',
                    'tags' => '',
                    'title' => $post->title,
                    'description' => $body[0],
                    'url' => site_url($post->blog_slug),
                    'thumbnail' => base_url() . $post->preview_image
                )
            );
$postURL = 'https://'.$blog->name.'tumblr.com/post/'.$repsonse->id;
```